# Angular 2 directive bind

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to bind "ngFor" index in custom directive as attribute
What did I do wrong?

this code:

```
@Directive({selector: '[closeWeb]'})
class CountClicks {
    numberOfClicks = 0;
    @HostListener('touchstart', ['$event.target'])
    touchstart(btn) {
        console.log(btn)
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'wrap',
    template: `
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="item" *ngFor="#webviews of webviewsCount; #i = index">

                <!-- I want to bind index in custom directive as attribute -->
                <div [closeWeb]="i">{{i}}</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [CountClicks]
})

export class Wrap {}
```

And I get this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'closeWeb' since it isn't a known native property ("</div><div [ERROR ->][closeWeb]="i">{{i}}</div></div></div>"): Wrap@9:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the annotation to your `numberOfClicks` attribute in your directive:

```
@Directive({selector: '[closeWeb]'})
class CountClicks {
  @Input('closeWeb')
  numberOfClicks = 0;

  (...)
}
```

This way you will define the `numberOfClicks` attribute as an input parameter of your directive and be able to get the value you provide when using the directive.

You could have a look at the angular.io documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html. See the section "Configure the directive with binding".

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not help to me. Then I add annotation, error disappear, but then I click on element, I have only tag without directive `<div>0</div>`. I want to get `<div closeweb="0">0</div>`

Comment: In fact, the directive is actually applied. I mean you can click several times on elements. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Lm4qnfcAhmTDXpELh6ib?p=preview. Why do you need the `closeweb` zttribute to be still there?

Comment: Working, thank you very much! This index as attribute need me for other functions in business logic (I upgrade code from Angular 1.4 to Angular 2). But I have one question, then you replace `touchstart` to `click` in this code `@HostListener('touchstart', ['$event.target']); touchstart(btn){console.log('click = '+btn+' - '+this.numberOfClicks); }` - you implement click as touchstart event, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component,Directive,Input,HostListener} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({selector: 'closeWeb'})
class CountClicks {
    @Input('closeWeb2')
    numberOfClicks = 0;
    @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
    touchstart(btn) {
        console.log('click = '+btn+' - '+this.numberOfClicks); 
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'wrap',
    template: `
        <div class="wrap">
            webviewsCount : {{webviewsCount | json}}<br/> 
            <div class="item" *ngFor="#webviews of webviewsCount; #i = index">

                <!-- I want to bind index in custom directive as attribute -->
                <div style="widhth:30px; height: 30px; border: solid 1px black"
                     ><closeWeb [closeWeb2]="i">{{i}}</closeWeb>{{i}}</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [CountClicks]
})

export class Wrap {
  constructor() {
    this.webviewsCount = [
      { value: 1 },
      { value: 2 },
      { value: 3 }
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer adds no value to the question. Question already has accepted answer and your has no explanation at all.